# Migrating a library alongside its dependencies to Android using the NDK

Tags: android, c++, opencv, boost, android-ndk

I'm interested in porting a relatively complex C++ library, which uses cmake for compilation, to Android.

While the NDK can now support cmake compilation, this package depends on several other libs which can be easily installed on linux but are not available for Android (boost, tbb, blas).

Is there any simple solution for porting such a library with all its dependencies? Do I have to start by porting each dependency on its own? (Specifically, I'm porting the [OpenFace](https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace) project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, unless you can find cases where other people have already ported the library, you'll have to do that yourself. Lots of common libraries (including boost) have a few ports that you can find with a quick Google search, but you'll probably still need to port a few on your own.